# How to namespace methods that do not belong in the actual plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I got some extension points in my plugin that I provide some default implementations for. Those objects does not belong in my methods object but should still be namespaced properly.

How do I namespace those extensions?

I tried to do this:

```
(function ($) {
    var pageManagers = {};
    var themeManagers = { };

    themeManagers.noTheme = {
        some: function() {
        }
        // and more.
    }

   var methods = {
      // all of my methods
   }


    $.fn.griffinTable = function (method) {
        if (methods[method]) {
            return methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof method === 'object' || !method) {
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' + method + ' does not exist on jQuery.griffinTable');
        }

        return this;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

But I can't figure out how to access `pageManagers` or `themeManagers` from the outside like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#mytable').griffinTable({ fetchAtStart: true, themeManager: themeManagers.noTheme });
    });
</script>
```

How do I namespace and use them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this outside the jQuery scope:

```
$.griffinTableExtensions = {
    pageManagers: {},
    themeManagers: {}
};
```

Which allows me to use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#mytable').griffinTable({ fetchAtStart: true, themeManager: $.griffinTableExtensions.themeManagers.noTheme });
    });
</script>
```

I just committed the table plugin: https://github.com/jgauffin/Griffin.Table